# Precalculate OLAP cube inside Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, olap, olap-cube, azure-synapse

We have dimensinal model with fact tables of 100-300 GBs in parquet each. We build PBI reports on top of Azure Synapse (DirectQuery) and experience performance issues on slicing/dicing and especially on calculating multiple KPIs. In the same time data volume is pretty expensive to be kept in Azure Analysis Services. Because of number of dimensions, the fact table can't be aggregated significantly, so PBI import mode or composite model isn't an option as well.

Azure Synapse Analytics [faciliates OLAP operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), like GROUP BY ROLLUP/CUBE/GROUPING SETS.

1. *How can I benefit from Synapse's OLAP operations support?*
2. *Is that possible to pre-calculate OLAP cubes inside Synapse in order to boost PBI reports performance? How?*
3. *If the answer is yes, is that recomended to pre-calculate KPIs? Means moving KPIs definition to DWH OLAP cube level - is it an anti-pattern?*

P.S. using separate aggreagations for each PBI visualisation is not an option, it's more an exception from the rule. Synapse is clever enough to take the benefit from materialized view aggregation even on querying a base table, but this way you can't implement RLS and managing that number of materialized views also looks cumbersome.

### Upd for @NickW

Could you please answer the following sub-questions:

1. Have I got it right - OLAP operations support is mainly for downstream cube providers, not for Warehouse performance?
2. Is spawning Warehouse with materialized views in order to boost performance is considered a common practice or an anti-pattern? I've found (see [the link](https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2020/09/microsoft-ignite-announcements-2020/)) Power BI can create materialized views automatically based on query patterns. Still I'm afraid it won't be able to provide a stable testable solution, and RLS support again.
3. Is KPIs pre-calculation at Warehouse side considered as a common way or an anti-pattern? As I understand this is usually done no cube provider side, but if I haven't got one?
4. Do you see any other options to boost the performance? I can think only about reducing query parallelism by using PBI composite model and importing all dimensions to PBI. Not sure if it'd help.

Comment: Hi - please can you clarify where your data is being stored? You say you are using Azure Synapse but mentioned Parquet when giving the data size - is your data stored outside of Synapse and is being accessed from Synapse via external tables?

Comment: @NickW currently the flow looks like: `Databricks => ADLS gen2 (delta format) => Synapse (internal tables) => PBI`. The data are loaded from ADLS to Synapse internal tables. I expect Synapse and parquet to have comprable data volumes, since both a columnar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synapse [Result Set Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/performance-tuning-result-set-caching#:%7E:text=When%20result%20set%20caching%20is%20enabled%2C%20Synapse%20SQL,improves%20query%20performance%20and%20reduces%20compute%20resource%20usage.) and [Materialized Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-materialized-view-performance-tuning#:%7E:text=Materialized%20views%20vs.%20standard%20views%20%20%20,%20%20Fast%20%202%20more%20rows%20) can both help.

In the future the creation and maintence of Materialized Views will be automated.

> Azure Synapse will automatically create and manage materialized views
> for larger Power BI Premium datasets in DirectQuery mode. The
> materialized views will be based on usage and query patterns. They
> will be automatically maintained as a self-learning, self-optimizing
> system. Power BI queries to Azure Synapse in DirectQuery mode will
> automatically use the materialized views. This feature will provide
> enhanced performance and user concurrency.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2020wave2/power-bi/synapse-integration

[Power BI Aggregations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-aggregations) can also help.  If there are a lot of dimensions, select the most commonly used to create aggregations.

Comment: @DawidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for your answer! I have too many dimensions to create aggregations of import-feasible size. Is that possible to manage Row-Level Security over auto-created materialized views at Synapse? Is that a good idea to include KPIs into aggregations?

Comment: @Dawid Browne - Microsoft what do you usually do if you have about 20+ dimensions per fact table and different reports use different dimensions. Are you trying to group reports by dimensions-group and create a few aggregation tables at Warehouse side?

Comment: If PowerBI enforces the row-level security, the predicates will be included in the queries sent to Synapse.  I have no information about whether the upcoming auto-created materialized views will support RLS.  And it's not generally _possible_ let alone a good idea to include KPI and Measure definitions in aggregations.

Comment: "Are you trying to group reports by dimensions-group and create a few aggregation tables at Warehouse side"  That's the basic idea.  Also the aggregation might use a non-key attribute of the dimension, eg Week, not Day, Category, not ProductId.   You can also create the aggregation tables in Power BI as Dual or Import tables, as they are typically quite small.

Comment: PBI team suggested us to manage RLS on both sides: PBI and Synapse. I can hardly recollect the reasons now, it was far ago... I suppose that business users may want to access Warehouse directly, in the same time PBI requires on-side RLS configs for Import mode. Correct me pls if I'm wrong

Comment: That's right.  RLS in Synapse is for direct access to the Warehouse.  The PowerBI model should have its own RLS model, but they might both use the same data for mapping users to rows.  Having the RLS in PowerBI allows you to use Import and Dual mode tables, and enables Result Set Caching.

Comment: thank you! But how then PBI manage to auto-create views? Could it exposure a sensitive information then? If PBI creates views based on RLS rules, then it's not clear how, because it should create a view per each security group...

Comment: sorry for another dump question, I'm totally new to cube solutions. How does metrics precalculation in OLAP cubes differs from KPIs precalculation? As far as I understand OLAP cubes, they just aggregate metrics based on all possible dimensions combinations. So when user slicing/dicing, OLAP cube has the results ready w/o additional calculations.

Comment: Aggregations pre-calculate simple aggregates like SUM, COUNT, and SumOfSquares.  More complicated Measures and KPIs consume these, but typically can't be simply pre-calculated on partial aggregates and rolled up.  Something like Year-Over-Year-Same-Store-Sales-Growth-Percentage, just doesn't make sense on a (store,day,product) aggregate table.

Answer (score 1):

to hopefully answer some of your questions...

1. You can't pre-calculate OLAP cubes in Synapse; the closest you could get is creating aggregate tables and you've stated that this is not a viable solution
2. OLAP operations can be used in queries but don't "pre-build" anything that can be used by other queries (ignoring CTEs, sub-queries, etc.). So if you have existing queries that don't use these functions then re-writing them to use these functions might improve performance - but only for each specific query

I realise that your question was about OLAP but the underlying issue is obviously performance. Given that OLAP is unlikely to be a solution to your performance issues, I'd be happy to talk about performance tuning if you want?

### Update 1 - Answers to additional numbered questions

1. I'm not entirely sure I understand the question so this may not be an answer: the OLAP functions are there so that it is possible to write queries that use them. There can be an infinite number of reasons why people might need to to write queries that use these functions
2. Performance is the main (only?) reason for creating materialised views. They are very effective for creating datasets that will be used frequently i.e. when base data is at day level but lots of reports are aggregated at week/month level. As stated by another user in the comments, Synapse can manage this process automatically but whether it can actually create aggregates that are useful for a significant proportion of your queries is obviously entirely dependent on your particular circumstances.
3. KPI pre-calculation. In a DW any measures that can be calculated in advance should be (by your ETL/ELT process). For example, if you have reports that use Net Sales Amount (Gross Sales - Tax) and your source system is only providing Gross Sales and Tax amounts then your should be calculating Net Sales as a measure when loading your fact table. Obviously there are KPIs that can't be calculated in advance (i.e. probably anything involving averages) and these need to be defined in your BI tool
4. Boosting Performance: I'll cover this in the next section as it is a longer topic

### Boosting Performance

Performance tuning is a massive subject - some areas are generic and some will be specific to your infrastructure; this is not going to be a comprehensive review but will highlight a few areas you might need to consider.

Bear in mind a couple of things:

1. There is always an absolute limit on performance - based on your infrastructure - so even in a perfectly tuned system there is always going to be a limit that may not be what you hoped to achieve. However, with modern cloud infrastructure the chances of you hitting this limit are very low
2. Performance costs money. If all you can afford is a Mini then regardless of how well you tune it, it is never going to be as fast as a Ferrari

Given these caveats, a few things you can look at:

1. Query plan. Have a look at how your queries are executing and whether there are any obvious bottlenecks you can then focus on. This link give some further information [Monitor SQL Workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor)
2. Scale up your Synapse SQL pool. If you throw more resources at your queries they will run quicker. Obviously this is a bit of a "blunt instrument" approach but worth trying once other tuning activities have been tried. If this does turn out to give you acceptable performance you'd need to decide if it is worth the additional cost. [Scale Compute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/quickstart-scale-compute-portal)
3. Ensure your statistics are up to date
4. Check if the distribution mechanism (Round Robin, Hash) you've used for each table is still appropriate and, on a related topic, check the skew on each table
5. Indexing. Adding appropriate indexes will speed up your queries though they also have a storage implication and will slow down data loads. This article is a reasonable starting point when looking at your indexing: [Synapse Table Indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-index)
6. Materialised Views. Covered previously but worth investigating. I think the automatic management of MVs may not be out yet (or is only in public preview) but may be something to consider down the line
7. Data Model. If you have some fairly generic facts and dimensions that support a lot of queries then you might need to look at creating additional facts/dimensions just to support specific reports. I would always (if possible) derive them from existing facts/dimensions but you can create new tables by dropping unused SKs from facts, reducing data volumes, sub-setting the columns in tables, combining tables, etc.

Hopefully this gives you at least a starting point for investigating your performance issues.

Comment: thank you for the great answer! Yeah, I'll appreciate the further discussion. I've updated the question